# Why are the JSON objects empty?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dapper

I've got a GET entry point on `UsersController`. But this one is responding an array of empty objects. When I debug the entry point, the list (`IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`) is not empty and `UserViewModels` are not empty either.

But here is what it does respond:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

And the controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserViewModel>> Get()
{
    var u = _stObjMap.Default.Obtain<UserTable>();
    using (var ctx = new SqlStandardCallContext())
    {
        var a =  await ctx[u].Connection.QueryAsync<UserViewModel>("SELECT UserId, UserName, PrimaryEMail, CreationDate from CK.vUser where UserId <> 0 and UserId <> 1");
        return a;
    }
}
```

I really don't think that the problem is coming from the controller.
I'm using Dapper.I really don't know what is happening. And I have to write a lot because I can't edit this post

Comment: No I have no idea because I am not a magician unfortunately. Thus, I can only help if I see your code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all relevant code here.

Comment: Alex I think the issue is in the GET so paste that code instead.

Comment: The list is not null... and objects into this are not too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `UserViewModel` has no public properties defined.

Which is why no key value pairs are displayed when the object is serialized to JSON.

Based on the query, make sure there are matching properties in the model for the Dapper query to map the selected columns

```
public class UserViewModel
    public int UserId { get; set; } 
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryEMail { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The problem was that my model does not had { get; set} at the end of each properties. Try adding that.